# Run SystemD user service after resume/lock screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

I do have a SystemD user service that powers on an external sound card and external speakers. The unit works great when I initially log in with my user. After resuming the behaviour is different - I guess because I am already logged in but dropped to the lock screen.

How could I achieve to have my service unit to be executed when resuming or after returning from the lock screen?